# belongsToMany doesn't return the expected query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

In my application I have a table called `users`, each user can have one or multiple roles ([I'm using laratrust](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/6.x/usage/roles-and-permissions.html)), in this scenario I will cover the `tenant` and the `patient` role.

The package [santigator/laratrust](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/6.x/usage/roles-and-permissions.html) handle the role within this tables:

- **roles**: all the roles available
- **role_user**: pivot table

Now, my app allows `patient` users to invite other users to register to the app, and they will automatically have the role of `tenant`. The `patient` user must also associate one or more `riskareas` for the invited user. In this way the "tenant" will have access only to certain areas of the `patient` user.

I handle the situation above in the `invites` table, this is the design to explain better:

[image]

The problem here is that we have a single users model that manages multiple roles (`patient` and `tenant`) and I have to make sure that the user model is able to return the `tenant`s associated with a patient and vice versa.

So I though to declare in the `User` model two methods: `patients()` and `tenants()`, I started with the `patients` method:

```
public function patients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'invites')->withPivot('tenant_id');
}
```

when I do:

```
dd(auth()->user()->patients()->toSql());
```

It returns the following query:

```
"select * from `users` inner join `invites` on `users`.`id` = `invites`.`user_id` where `invites`.`user_id` = ? and `users`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

which returns an empty collection, the query should return this:

```
"select * from `users` inner join `invites` on `users`.`id` = `invites`.`user_id` where `invites`.`tenant_id` = ? and `users`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

I'm not sure if I'm handling this situation correctly. Someone could give me an help on this?

Kind regards

**UPDATE**

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
    User::class,
    Invite::class,
    'tenant_id',
    'id',
    '123',
    'user_id'
);
```

RESULT:

```
"select * from `users` inner join `invites` on `invites`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `invites`.`tenant_id` is null and `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `invites`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

Why: `where` invites`.`tenant_id `is null` ?

Comment: Looks like you should focus on [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Comment: Have you tried this: `return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'invites', 'tenant_id', 'user_id');`? (not sure about the order of `tenant_id` and `user_id` though)

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier thanks, seems working. If you reply I will accept the answer

Comment: @sfarzoso Feel free to edit my answer if it the order of the foreign key are reversed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with your foreign keys:

```php
public function patients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'invites', 'user_id', 'tenant_id');
}
```

More info about `belongsToMany`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure

Comment: Side note: You can also use `->wherePivot('status', 'accepted')->withPivot('status')` if that's a need